# Trend chart in Qlik Sense not changing on user selections after applying set analysis on the trend chart

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis

I have a trend chart in Qlik Sense where I have applied the following condition to filter the data :

```
avg({$<DATA_SUBJECT_NAME={'CALL','ACCOUNT','IDENTITY','FINANCIALTRANSACTIONS','HOUSEHOLD','FLOWS','INTERACTIONS'}>}HEALTH_KPI_NUM)
```

The chart is displayed perfectly but when I make other selections on the sheet the chart remains unaffected. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you are selecting in `DATA_SUBJECT` field the chart will stay the same. With this set analysis in the expression the chart will show result only for the values in the set analysis and ignore all selections in `DATA_SUBJECT` field

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as Stefan said. If you are selecting in the field that you have already applied set analysis to there will be no change as the set analysis will override the selections. You can try this if you want the selections to be honoured

```
avg({$<DATA_SUBJECT_NAME*={'CALL','ACCOUNT','IDENTITY','FINANCIALTRANSACTIONS','HOUSEHOLD','FLOWS','INTERACTIONS'}>}HEALTH_KPI_NUM)
```

The only change is to add *= this says the set analysis should be the intersection of the actual selection and the provided list